# Create a Flow that constantly runs in background

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, power-automate, ms-flow

I am trying to see if this is achievable. I have a list that contains users birthdays. When a new user is added to the list, obviously the flow would trigger, checking that new item and is stuck in phase 2 until it is a week before the users birthday to send a notification/reminder email. Then after that, it doesn't do it the next year.

Is it possible to have a flow that runs from a list, and constantly checks items to see if the birthday column date is close to the current date? Instead of triggering on creation, waiting (with the possibility of failing because how far out it could be), then actually going through.

**UPDATE:**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks , I tried the following from this article, but it tells me that there is no dynamic content available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your flow is running on a schedule, it is not directly associated with a SharePoint List and therefore does not have context/awareness. Hence: no dynamic content available. If you add a Query List Action you will be able to get items from that List and process as needed. Here's a post with a similar Question/Answer:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Filter-Get-SharePoint-Items-for-Scheduled-Flow/td-p/489974

Comment: Thanks Omar! Checking out that article now!